# jQuery offset() not working in some browsers, on some computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, jquery-autocomplete

I have a problem positioning an element in certain browsers.  I'm using the jQuery autocomplete found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/).  The div containing autocomplete values should be directly under the text box, and line up perfectly.  The code sets the css left property of the div by using the left property generated by `$(textbox).offset();`

After un-packing the code to try and fix my problem, I get this:

```
var a = $(textbox).offset();
element.css({
    width: typeof e.width == "string" || e.width > 0 ? e.width : $(textbox).width(),
    top: a.top + textbox.offsetHeight,
    left: a.left
}).show();
```

This seems like it should work, and it does work in Firefox.  It doesn't work in IE8, Chrome.  The top position is always correct, but the sometimes the div is too far to the left, or too far to the right.

On different computers (all with Windows XP), it works in IE8... how can this be?  I've also tested it on my Mac, OS 10.5.  It works in Firefox, but not Safari.

I've disabled plug-ins, changed screen resolutions, re-sized windows... It just inconsistently works in some places sometimes.

Can anyone think of something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**:
I have re-worked my code to use the autocomplete supplied with jQuery 1.4.2 and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) 1.8rc3.  It is still broken, same problem.  Please help!

**UPDATE 2**:
See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456005/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-working-in-ie).  jQuery UI autocomplete breaks because it uses offset.  Does anyone have a work around?

Here is the javascript from the UI autocomplete function that trips up:

```
.css({ top: (offset.top + this.element.height) + 'px', left: offset.left + 'px' })
```

If it is changed to `top: '0px', left: '0px'` it works fine, but is obviously positioned in the wrong spot.

Comment: x64 vs x32 rendering engines?

Comment: @Josh: not sure what you mean. All computers have 32 bit processors, and 32 bit windows xp

Comment: This "offset" vs. "position" thing always confuses me. If this were my code, I'd try: (A) use "position()" instead of "offset()" and (B) see what happens when I wrap the problematic HTML in a "position: relative" div.

Comment: @peter - just wondering if you had checked to see if it is an x64 OS/browser issue since you mentioned that it works. Another thing to check is what differences there are in any updates applied to each machine, since IIRC, MS released some patches in the last few months that could possibly affect IE rendering

Comment: @Peter, have you checked that "position" of the element is set to "absolute"?

Comment: @Pointy: offset() is correct to use since it is in relation to the document, position() is in relation to the container.  I tried changing using position() anyway, and it appeared in the top corner of the screen, as expected.

Comment: @prometheus: The position is set to absolute, if I change it to relative, it appears at the bottom of the page **with the correct left position** but the top position is no longer correct since this element is appended to the end of `<body>` with js.

Comment: I had this issue with the original autocomplete plugin (not jQueryUI), and I traced it to setting scrollHeight to 'auto'. Once I removed the line (or changed 'auto' to a numeric value), it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening.  I had a css rule defining the width of the body:

```
body {
    width: 900px;
}
```

Once I changed this to `width: 100%;` and enclosed the entire page in a div of width 900px, it worked as expected.

It looks like IE uses the body element to measure top and left values for `offset()`, but uses the window edge when to measure top and left distances when positioning an item absolutely.

I hope this answer will save someone else all the time I've wasted on this...

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar question,finally discovered the `float` property affects `relative`,making the `relative` div not stable in Internet Explorer 8 but performs well in firefox.