# jQuery UI autocomplete works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got the new autocomplete widget in jQuery UI 1.8rc3 working great in Firefox.  It doesn't work at all in IE.  Can someone help me out?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="ctrSearch" size="30">
<input type="hidden" id="ctrId">
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#ctrSearch").autocomplete({
    source: "ctrSearch.do",
    minLength: 3,
    focus: function(event, ui){
        $('#ctrSearch').val(ui.item.ctrLastName + ", " + ui.item.ctrFirstName);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#ctrId').val(ui.item.ctrId);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Result (IE 8):**

The red box is the `<ul>` element created by jQuery.

[image]

I also get this error:

```
Line: 116
Error: Invalid argument.
```

When I open it in the IE8 script debugger, it highlights `f[b]=d` on line 116 of jquery.min.js.  Note that I'm using version 1.4.2 of jQuery hosted on Google's servers (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js).

I've tried removing some of the options, but even when I call `.autocomplete()` with no options, or with only the source option, I still get the same result.

Once again, it's working in Firefox, but not in IE.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**  As suggested, I used jquery.js (instead of jquery.min.js) and got the error on line 4618.  See jitter's answer below.  Please see [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426802/jquery-offset-not-working-in-some-browsers-on-some-computers) that was posted a few days ago.

**UPDATE 2:**  I discovered that jQuery UI autocomplete uses an invalid property `this.element.height`, when it should be using the function `this.element.height()`

Comment: Peter. Don't use the minified version of jQuery for debugging. There's likely more info than "f[b]=d on line 116 of jquery.min.js" available if you swap for jQuery.js instead.

Comment: spender is right. While developing swap out the minified version vs. the full blown jQuery http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js to get better debugging infos

Comment: If I find time I might look into this tomorrow. Don't have an IE8 available right now

Comment: Thanks jitter.  Looking forward to your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this right the line you refer to seems to be the line 4618 in [jquery.1.4.2.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js) in the `style` function. Which can only mean that the Autocompleter plugin tries to set a style value that IE8 doesn't understand or doesn't allow to be accessed/changed in this way.

```
style[ name ] = value; //style == elem.style from the passed in element
```

Comment: I discovered that jQuery UI autocomplete uses an invalid property this.element.height, when it should be using the function this.element.height()

Comment: Ok great that you figured this out. Did you make a bug report on the jQuery UI issue tracker?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same error on the exact same line, but for a completely different deal. That is, I'm not doing anything having to do with auto-complete; rather, mine occurs because I'm trying this in jQuery...

```
$(this).css('background', 'rgba(64,255,64,.4)');
```

Which jQuery tries to do...

```
style [ 'background' ] = 'rgba(64,255,64,.4)';
```

And it fails, of course, because rgba is not a supported CSS value for Internet Explorer. So you're not alone on this one, but in my case I was just doing it wrong. The appropriate jQuery syntax is this...

```
$(this).css({backgroundColor: '#40ff40', opacity: .4});
```

Here's my source...

http://www.cjs.me.uk/blog/?p=238

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 4618 as well... where 'value' is null. This happens with .effect('highlight', {}, 1000)