# Getting different values for offset in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get offset().top value for a single element using jQuery:

```
var offset = $('#some_id').offset().top;
```

I get same value in webkit, but different one in Firefox, which is higher. Is that normal?

Comment: Got a test case for us? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [offsetTop vs. jQuery.offset().top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777506/offsettop-vs-jquery-offset-top)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426802/jquery-offset-not-working-in-some-browsers-on-some-computers 

"It looks like IE uses the body element to measure top and left values for offset(), but uses the window edge when to measure top and left distances when positioning an item absolutely."

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset stylesheet? Are you sure your page is rendering the same, pixel per pixel, in both browsers?

Comment: It's a huge code: http://jsbin.com/ihadem/1/edit. I simplified the JS code. I don't used any reset, but I have a *{margin/padding} thing. Which I think should be enough for the offset.

Comment: I have tried to use `position()` instead of `offset()`. It comes a little closer, but still too much diference in Firefox.

Comment: Also added a normalize.css just for testing; same results.